# Database - Query failed when we try to insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I can't seem to get my Database to insert a customer...

It's in danish (the tags) but i think you can understand what happens anyways. We do connect to the database on the website, but it saids query failed...

Here's my contact form code:

```
<form action="elev.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
        <label for="navn" style="float:left;">Navn:</label>
        <input type="text" id="navn" name="navn" placeholder="Andreas Andreasen" />

                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Andreasandreasen@hotmail.com" />

                    <label for="telefonnummer">Telefon:</label>
        <input type="number" id="telefonnummer" name="telefonnummer" placeholder="12345678" />

                    <label for="postnummer">Postnr:</label>
        <input type="text" id="postnummer" name="postnummer" placeholder="8000" />

        <input style="float:right;" type="submit" value="Opret" name="submit" />

        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <form action="index.php">
            <input style="float:left; margin-top:-51px;" type="submit" value="Startsiden">
    </form>
```

Here's my PHP code for the database:(my password is not xxxxx, that's just to protect the database :) but it does say "connect succes! so i believe that is not the problem.

The problem comes when we try to put in a new customer and it saids query failed, the customerid = kundeid is incremental so we do not have that on the form.

```
    <?php
$mysqli=mysqli_connect("localhost", "f413f_gr6", "xxxxxx", "f413f_gr6");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_errno(); }
else {
    echo "Connect success!<br>"; }

    function performQuery($sql) {       
    global $mysqli;     
    if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {          
    echo "Query Success!";      }
    else {          
    echo "Query Failed!";       }   
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $navn = $_POST['navn'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telefonnummer = $_POST['telefonnummer'];
    $postnummer = $_POST['postnummer'];

    performQuery("INSERT INTO kunder(navn, email, telefonnummer, postnummer) VALUES ('$navn', '$email', $telefonnummer, '$postnummer')");
    }
    else {
    echo "Tryk på submit"; 
     }        
?>
```

And here's a picture of our database:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG4d5.jpg

Comment: You said query failed. What error it shows?

Comment: also echo `$mysqli->error` in the else part .

Comment: Can you write the exact echo code cause i don't know how to insert it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think issues in your query with `postnummer` is int data type as you shared database image so please replace your query with below query i will helps you.

```
performQuery("INSERT INTO kunder(navn, email, telefonnummer, postnummer) VALUES ('$navn', '$email', $telefonnummer, $postnummer)");
```

Replace your query with above i hope your issues will solve.your are trying to insert as string for postnummer may the reason you are getting error actually in your database datatype is int.

Comment: Unfortunately it wasnt the problem... but thanks anyway for the help.